# Django. Использование fields для CreateView для моделей с OneToOneField

Tags: django

Пытаюсь создать пользователя с помощью функции CreateView, имея следующую модель:

models.py

```
class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                models.DO_NOTHING)
    phone_number_c      = PhoneNumberField(null=False,
                                        blank=False,
                                        unique=True,
                                        verbose_name="Номер телефона")
    phone_show_b        = models. BooleanField(verbose_name="Показывать номер телефона")
```

view.py

```
class UserProfileInfoCreateView(CreateView):
    fields = ('user.first_name','user.last_name','phone_number_c')
```

При этом выходит ошибка:
Unknown field(s) (user.first_name, user.last_name) specified for UserProfileInfo

Answer (score 0):

Либо Вы привели не полный код либо Ваш класс ни чего не знает о модели с которой работает.

```
class UserProfileInfoCreateView(CreateView):
    model = UserProfileInfo
    #Общее правило. Для обращения к связанным моделям используется '__'
    fields = ['user__first_name','user__last_name','phone_number_c']
    #fields это картеж
```

> Подробнее о классе CreateView см. официальную документацию
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView
>   .

Comment: Благодарю. UserProfileInfo соединен с встроенным классом User - фактически я расширяю класс user. в какой части привести код?